# Date filter is applied on all tabs of datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have 3 tabs (pending, published and archived) each is composed of the following HTML code:

**HTML for pending tab**

```
<label for="pending-fromDate">publication Date from</label>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="pending-fromDate"> 

<label for="pending-toDate">publication Date from</label>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="pending-toDate">

<button type="button" id="resetButton-pending">Reset</button>

<table id="pending-data-table" style="width: 100%;"
    class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped js-dashboard-table">
    <thead>
        <tr id="pending-data-table-col">
            <th data-column-id="id-pending">Id</th>
            <th data-column-id="name-pending">name</th>
            <th data-column-id="publication-pending">publication Date</th>
            <th data-column-id="closing-pending">closing Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The problem is that when I apply a date filter on a tab and then I click on rest button on other tab, the content of all tables responds to the filter. It is like all datatables are dependent.

This is my JS code:

**JS**

```
var tabName = $('#pending-data-table'); 

tabName.dataTable({
    initComplete : function() {
        var table = tabName.DataTable();
            $('#pending-rows-number').text('(' + this.api().data().count() + ')');
            searchDatesField(table, 2, 'pending-fromDate', 'pending-toDate', 'pending');
        //...
    }
});

function searchDatesField(table, columnIndex, fieldNameFrom, fieldNameTo, tabName) {


var datax = table.rows().data();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, datax, dataIndex) {
        var max, min;
        var fromDate = $('#'+ fieldNameFrom).val();
        var toDate = $('#'+ fieldNameTo).val();

        if (fromDate.length > 0){
            min = getFilterDateValue(fromDate);
        } else {
            min = null;
        }

        if (toDate.length > 0){
            max = getFilterDateValue(toDate);;
        } else {
            max = null;
        }

        var filterDate = new Date(datax[columnIndex].substring(0,4) + '-' 
                + datax[columnIndex].substring(4,6) + '-' 
                + datax[columnIndex].substring(6,8));

        if (min == null && max == null){
            return true;
        } else if (min == null && max != null ){
            if (filterDate <= max){
                return true;
            }
        } else if(min != null && max == null ){
            if(filterDate >= min){
                return true;
            }
        } else if (min != null && max != null) { 
            if(filterDate >= min && filterDate <= max){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    });

    initDatePickerActions(fieldNameFrom, table, tabName);
    initDatePickerActions(fieldNameTo, table, tabName);
}   

function initDatePickerActions(dateField, table, tabName){
    $('#'+ dateField).Zebra_DatePicker({
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        onSelect: function(view, elements){
            table.draw();
            if(tabName != ''){
                updateTableRowsNumber(table, $('#'+ tabName +'-rows-number'));
            }
        },
        onClear: function(view, elements){
            table.draw();
            if(tabName != ''){
                updateTableRowsNumber(table, $('#'+ tabName +'-rows-number'));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And the button allows to reset all fields:

```
function resetSearchFields(tabName) {
    var fieldSelector = '#search-filters';

    if(tabName != ''){
        fieldSelector = '#'+ tabName +'-tab';
    }

    $(fieldSelector +' .datepicker').each(function() {
        $(this).data('Zebra_DatePicker').clear_date();
    });

    $(fieldSelector +' select').each(function() {
        $(this).val('All').change();
    });

    $(fieldSelector +' input:not(.datepicker)').each(function(){
        $(this).val('').keyup();
    });
}
```

Do you have any idea how to make the reset applicable only on the active tab filters??

Thank you

Comment: I'm not clear as to why you're doing `var table = tabName.DataTable();` *inside* your dataTable init ?  I would expect something like `var table = tabName.dataTable({ ...`

Comment: @devlincarnate I used the variable table as a parameter for the function searchDatesField.

Comment: I get that...but it doesn't make sense to assign it where you are (or to re-init DataTable() (and also, pay attention to the difference between dataTable() and DataTable()!).  It makes sense to assign it in the outer init of your datatable (like in my example in the comment above).  And, you can still reference the variable inside your function...you actually won't have to pass it as a parameter given the scope).  However, if you have 3 tables, you will have 3 table variables....keep that in mind

Comment: @devlincarnate I see. But the problem I have other filters that work perfectly (Select, free text). I only have this issue with dates filter